# Disabling an angular tool-tip based on certain conditions

Tags: angular, typescript

I only wanted to enable tool-tip if a condition is true. I've tried something below but does not seem to work. Any idea that might help ? thanks.

Is this the right way of using it  matTooltipDisabled="row.statusLiteral !=== 'Test'" ?

```
  <resource-status-indicator [status]="row.status"
                [resource]="'data-test'"
                matTooltip= {{row.status}}
                matTooltipDisabled="row.statusLiteral !=== 'Test'"
              ></resource-status-indicator>
```

Comment: try: `[matTooltip]="condition?row.status:null"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator needs to be fixed: the strict "does-not-equal"-Operator is `!==` not `!===`.

And in order for angular to evaluate your expression you need to wrap it into `{{ }}`

```js
<resource-status-indicator 
    [status]="row.status" 
    [resource]="'data-test'"
    matTooltip= {{row.status}} 
    matTooltipDisabled="{{row.statusLiteral !== 'Test'}}" >
</resource-status-indicator>
```

or use property binding `[...]="..."`

```js
<resource-status-indicator 
    [status]="row.status" 
    [resource]="'data-test'"
    matTooltip= {{row.status}} 
    [matTooltipDisabled]="row.statusLiteral !== 'Test'" >
</resource-status-indicator>
```

Check out this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-22mwea)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use property binding in order for it to work:

```
[matTooltipDisabled]="row.statusLiteral !=== 'Test'"
```

Comment: so this needs some logic on the script /

Comment: @Developer, no just put the square bracquets as he did.

Comment: it says Error
    Angular 8 , @AakashGarg

Comment: import FormsModule in your imports array of module.